# Confused assembly code keywords

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, opcode

The page http://daeken.pastebin.ca/raw/843310 contains all assembly code with its descriptions. But I don't really understand, for example `0xa1 : ['MOV', 'rAX,Ov'],...`, look at its description I could not figure out what it means.

Here are tons of examples like this :

```
Ob - Ov - rAX - Yb - Xb - etc...
```

Could anyone explain what those strange symbols mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
0xa1 : ['MOV', 'rAX,Ov']
```

According to [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Developer's Manual: Combined Volumes](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.html) Table A-2. One-byte Opcode Map: (00H — F7H) `0xa1` is `mov rAX, Ov`.

Then table A.2.1 Codes for Addressing Method explains the abbreviations used in the addressing:

```
O The instruction has no ModR/M byte. The offset of the operand is coded as
a word or double word (depending on address size attribute) in the instruction.
No base register, index register, or scaling factor can be applied (for example,
MOV (A0–A3)).
```

Table A.2.2 Codes for Operand Type explains the operand type:

```
v Word, doubleword or quadword (in 64-bit mode), depending on operand-size
attribute.
```

And below A.2.3 Register Codes it says:

```
A register identifier of the form eXX or rXX is used when register width depends
on the operand-size attribute. eXX is used when 16 or 32-bit sizes are possible;
rXX is used when 16, 32, or 64-bit sizes are possible. For example: eAX indicates
that the AX register is used when the operand-size attribute is 16 and the EAX
register is used when the operand-size attribute is 32. rAX can indicate AX, EAX
or RAX.
```

So here are some example instruction encodings for `0xa1` opcode (confirmed with [`udcli -x`](http://udis86.sourceforge.net/)):

```
a10102               mov ax,  [0x201]             ; in x86 16-bit code
a101020304           mov eax, [0x4030201]         ; in x86 32-bit code
a10102030405060708   mov eax, [0x807060504030201] ; in x86-64

66a101020304         mov ax,  [0x4030201]         ; with 0x66, in x86 32-bit code
66a10102030405060708 mov ax,  [0x807060504030201] ; with 0x66, in x86-64

48a10102030405060708 mov rax, [0x807060504030201] ; with 0x48 REX.W, in x86-64
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the great `udcli -x` tool and examples! It makes perfect sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

[80806 Opcode Map](http://www.mlsite.net/8086/#addr_E)

In the bottom you'll find description for those